NodeTree missing input attribute
I am using the super image denoiser and when I click create SID, an error happens. Here is the code:
import bpy
from bpy.types import NodeTree
from .create_denoiser import create_denoiser

def create_sid_denoiser_standard() -> NodeTree:
    # Create standard quality denoiser node group
    prefilter_quality = 'FAST'

    sid_tree: NodeTree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type="CompositorNodeTree", name=".SuperImageDenoiser")
    input_node = sid_tree.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
    input_node.location = (-200, 0)

    output_node = sid_tree.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
    output_node.location = (800, 0)

    sid_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Noisy Image")
    sid_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketVector", "Denoising Normal")
    sid_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Denoising Albedo")

    # Standard Denoiser
    standard_dn = create_denoiser(sid_tree, location=(0, 100), prefilter_quality=prefilter_quality)

    # Link nodes
    sid_tree.links.new(input_node.outputs['Noisy Image'], standard_dn.inputs[0])
    sid_tree.links.new(input_node.outputs['Denoising Normal'], standard_dn.inputs[1])
    sid_tree.links.new(input_node.outputs['Denoising Albedo'], standard_dn.inputs[2])

    sid_tree.outputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Denoised Image")

    sid_tree.links.new(standard_dn.outputs[0], output_node.inputs["Denoised Image"])

    return sid_tree

Here is the error:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\SuperImageDenoiser\SuperImageDenoiser.py", line 83, in execute
    sid_standard_tree = create_sid_denoiser_standard()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\SuperImageDenoiser\SID_QualityStandart.py", line 16, in create_sid_denoiser_standard
    sid_tree.interface.new_socket("Noisy Image",in_out='INPUT', socket_type="NodeSocketColor")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CompositorNodeTree' object has no attribute 'inputs'

If anyone can help that would be great.

Hello. Bryan, if @Gorgious heads you in the right direction, could you let us know in a comment, here, please?

Ups sorry this was actually not a duplicate. I retracted the vote

If I run your script in Blender 4.1 then I get an error in line 16, in create_sid_denoiser_standard: AttributeError: 'CompositorNodeTree' object has no attribute 'inputs'. That's correct because the API has been changed in 4.0. But it makes me wonder why your error message "sid_tree.interface.new_socket" is mentioned. That's not in the code snippet shown above.

By the way, a link to the add-on would be helpful. If you used this one [Addon] Super Image Denoiser 4.0.0 (SID) then it won't work in Blender 4.1 because of the API change.


@Blunder Thanks for responding, the reason why it was changed was because I was trying to solve it, albeit unsuccessfully. 2. Robin Beets, I am not sure what you mean.


@Bryan thanks for the reply but we still don't know which Add-on version you have tried :-( The console shows you're using Blender 4.1, so you need to download the Pidgeon Tool Bag as stated in the linked description.
